# List all the available Notifications Ringtones in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to change the default sound of the Notification and I do like this:

```
     private void showNotification(Context context, String reminderid, String title, String shortinfo, String longinfo) 
     {
         mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         NOTIFICATION=Integer.parseInt(reminderid);
         Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, title,
             System.currentTimeMillis());
         PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
             new Intent(context, RemindersActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, shortinfo,
                    longinfo, contentIntent);  
         notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
         notification.sound = Uri.withAppendedPath(Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "6");
         notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

         mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
     }
```

But you can notice that I'm giving number the ID "6" for the `URI.withAppendedPath()`, I need to list all the available Notifications Ringtones for the user and let him choose, and I will pass the ID of what he choose instead of "6".

Here Google says:

> In this case, the exact ID of the media file ("6") is known and appended to the content Uri. If you don't know the exact ID, you must query all the media available in the MediaStore with a ContentResolver. See the Content Providers documentation for more information on using a ContentResolver.

How can I do what they say (note that I never worked with content providers or resolvers)? and give the user the option to choose the ringtone for notification like choosing it in phone settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add sound to your raw folder, initialize it

```
MediaPlayer mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.slow);
```

and call it where ever required

```
    mpSplash.start();
```

Comment: I know this, but I don't want to choose custom sound, I want to choose one of the default sound like when go to settings in android and change Notification sound.